# How to calculate the average of last 100 numbers of increasing quantity of numbers pool

Tags: c, algorithm, math, data-structures, average

I have a data source.  It gives a number each minute.  I want to compute the average value of the last  100 numbers.  How do I do this with C?

For example, the input is `1,2,3,4, ... 150` then I want to get the average value of `50 . . . 150`.

One minute later, the number pool changes to `1,2,3,4.....150,151`, then I need to get the  average value of `51. . . 151`, as the concept is same,  get the last 100 numbers to calculate the average value.

I have tried to use a list structure, first get get total sum of all the numbers ,then subtract the sum from the first number to `count-100` to get the last 100 numbers .

Here is my code i have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#define N 5

int i,sum;

int main(void)
{
struct node //定义一个链表
{
    float num;  //链表的元素
    struct node *next;//下一个元素的指针
};
struct node *first=NULL;//第一个数据
struct node *current=NULL;//当前的数据
struct node *previous=NULL;//上一个数据

struct node *currentT=NULL;//
//    char temp='\0';

while (1==1)//循环输入数据，相当于每秒往链表中添加一个数据
{
    // printf("continue ?Y/N:  ");
    // scanf(" %c",&temp);

    // if (tolower(temp)=='n')
    //  break;
    current=(struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));//获取链表的首地址
    if (first==NULL)//如果第一个数据为空就把当前的地址赋值给first
        first=current;
    if (previous!=NULL)//把当前的地址赋值给上一个数据的next指针
        previous->next=current;
    printf("please enter the num:");
    scanf("%f",&current->num);//输入数据
    current->next=NULL;//移动指针
    previous=current;

    currentT=first;//指针指向第一个数据
    float avg=0,sum=0,count=0;
    while (currentT!=NULL)//循环链表中所有的数据
    {
        printf("node's num is:%f \n",currentT->num);
        count=count+1;
        sum= sum+currentT->num;//求总和
        currentT=currentT->next;//指针下移

    }
    avg=sum/count;//求平均

    if(count>N)//如果链表长度大于N则减去链表前端的数据
    {
        currentT=first;//指针指向第一个数据
        int remove_count=0;
        while (currentT!=NULL)//循环链表中所有的数据
        {
            remove_count=remove_count+1;
            sum= sum-currentT->num;//求总和
            if(remove_count==count-N){//减到链表长度等于N时停止
                break;
            }
            currentT=currentT->next;//指针下移
        }
         avg=sum/N;//求平均
    }

    printf("sum is:%f \n",sum);

    printf("avg is:%f \n",avg);

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is those values comes in array?

Comment: Take the first number away from the sum, add the new number to the sum, divide by 100 again.

Comment: I don't care the source of data, i just use a scanf to simulate the data .

Comment: I think should you implement an array of circular buffer.

Comment: I need an array as the return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a implementation of circular queue using array, and a function to return average of the elements when adding a new element. The function deletes the 1st element when queue is full. So, you can just call this function for every input and it will return the average of current elements.

```
//declarations
#define MAXSIZE 5
int cq[MAXSIZE]={0};
int front=-1,rear=-1;
float AverageForNewElement(int);

//function definition 
float AverageForNewElement(int item)
{
    static int Sum=0;
    if(front ==(rear+1)%MAXSIZE)
    {
        if(front==rear)
            front=rear=-1;
        else
            front = (front+1)%MAXSIZE;
        Sum=Sum-cq[front];
    }
    if(front==-1)
        front=rear=0;
    else
        rear=(rear+1)%MAXSIZE;
    cq[rear]=item;
    Sum=Sum+cq[rear];
    return ((float)Sum/MAXSIZE);
}
```

Comment: You always divide by `MAXSIZE`. That's going to provide an incorrect average when the queue is not full.

Comment: I thought it is needed to calculate average of 100 elements, considering the rest as 0.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm seems simple. Keep the last 100 numbers which came in in some queue.
That queue will contain 100 elements at any moment of time. Also, you keep their sum S at any time. When a new number comes in, remove the first number from the queue, and add the new number which came in to the queue. Then just recalculate the sum S of these 100 numbers by subtracting the first number and adding the new one.

```
S = S - aOldFirst + aNewLast;
```

I would use a dynamic structure (e.g. a linked list) for implementing the queue.

Comment: You don't have too loop each time, you can also hold sum of 100 elements. And reduce it by popped element and increase it by new element each time an element is added

Comment: @taytay Right, yes, that's obvious. Thanks.

Comment: Why use a linked list when a circular buffer is easier and faster?

Comment: @JimMischel This is just my answer. I didn't say it's the perfect one. Others may respond too, right?